# How to add different background colour using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I want to provide a different background color for the angular ng-repeat in the table design format. If `play_id` is same I want to provide same background color in `tr` tag else another color  `tr` tag.

JSON (https://jsfiddle.net/0sasz78n/)

```
{
    "play_details": [
        {
            "play_id": "15",
            "quest_id": "63",
            "question": "What will be the match result ?"
        },
        {
            "play_id": "8",
            "quest_id": "61",
            "question": "Which of this batswan will score higher ?"
        },
        {
            "play_id": "8",
            "quest_id": "59",
            "question": "What will be the match result ?"
        }
    ]
}
```

**HTML code:**

```
<table><tr ng-repeat="single_Play in all_Play_details">
    <td>{{$index + 1}}</td>
    <td>{{single_Play.play_id}}</td>
    <td>{{single_Play.quest_id}}</td>
    <td>{{single_Play.question}}</td>
</tr></table>
```

**JS code:**

```
$scope.all_Play_details = response.data.play_details;
```

Comment: Your `jsfiddle` link has nothing.

Comment: {"play_details":[{"play_id":"8","quest_id":"61","question":"Which of this batswan will score higher ?"},{"play_id":"8","quest_id":"59","question":"What will be the match result ?"}]}

Comment: this is json format

Comment: You could use `ng-style`/`ng-class`, but before that include `backgroundColor` property in each element of your array

Comment: the play_id will change randomly, then how can provide ng-class

Answer (score 1):

You can use ng-class for that.
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass

Just create some classes with different background color, then add a condition in ng-class.

```
table><tr ng-repeat="single_Play in all_Play_details" ng-class="{'YOURCSSCLASS': single_Play.play_id == 8}>
...
 </tr></table>
```

Something like that should work.

To really fit your need (having the same background-color for every ID), you could also pass a function to ng-class. In this function, add some logic and return the good CSS class.
(logic could be to add have a scope array of object, like [{8: 'GREEN'}, {12: 'YELLOW'}] and everytime you go in this function, you add an object if the ID doesn't exist, and you associate a random color. If the ID already exist, you simply return the CSSproperty (like GREEN, fir play_ID 8)

Comment: can u please tell how to add that condition

Comment: main thing play_id change randomly , then how can provide statically play_id == 8

Comment: yeah, it was as an example. If play_id change randomly and is not in a range, you can add a background-color property to your JSON as Pankaj Parkar suggested.

Comment: However, setting a background-color depending on a random ID is kinda weird, if I can give my opinion.

Comment: is it possible to write like this ng-class="{'YOURCSSCLASS': single_Play.play_id =='next_play_id'} how to get this 'next_play_id'

Comment: You can't really guess what the next ID will be. See my updated answer to have a solution to your problem (maybe)

Comment: you r telling i have to update my json format right?

Comment: you don't have to touch your json in my last "solution". You just need to create a function in the controller to save the ID with the associated css class and return it.

You can call a function like that : ng-class="getBackgroundColour(play_id)"

Answer (score 1):

edit: ok, Rouk was faster ;)

I would suggest to use ng-class and add something like the following into your ng-repeat tag.

```
ng-class="{'highlightedCell' : play_details.play_id == currentID, 'diffentColoredCell' : play_details.play_id != currentID"}
```

and of course create the appropriate css-class.

Answer (score 0):

Just do like this :

```
 <table>
   <tr ng-repeat="single_Play in all_Play_details">
     <td>{{$index + 1}}</td>
     <td ng-class="{'background-color: yellow':single_Play.quest_id === 2 || single_Play.quest_id === 3 ,'background-color: red':single_Play.quest_id === 4}">{{single_Play.play_id}}</td>
     <td>{{single_Play.quest_id}}</td>
     <td>{{single_Play.question}}</td>
   </tr>
 </table>
```

Like this you can writes `ng-class` cases . hope it will help you